# Show login page link within error message in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
if( email_exists( $user['email'] ) ) {
        //Email address already registered
        leaky_paywall_errors()->add( 'email_used', __( 'This email address is already used', 'leaky_paywall' ), 'register' );
    }
```

The above code is for the error if the email is already exist. But now i want to add a login link with this message so that visitors can easily go to the login page by click.

```
if( email_exists( $user['email'] ) ) {
        //Email address already registered
        leaky_paywall_errors()->add( 'email_used', __( 'This email address is already used, Please go to login to complete the subscription:<a href=&quot;"https://example.de/login/&quot;">Click Here</a>', 'leaky_paywall' ), 'register' );
    }
```

But it always gives me double links such as if i mouse over on "Click Here" then I got the link like below...

```
local.dev/subscribe" "https://example.de/login" "
```

thanks

Comment: try removing the &quot; and actual quotes  and use  `\'`  instead 
`<a href=\'https://example.de/login/\'>Click Here</a`

Comment: Now I got a bit different result like: local.dev/"https://example.de/login//" @ Duane Lortie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if( email_exists( $user['email'] ) ) {
    //Email address already registered
    leaky_paywall_errors()->add( 'email_used', __( "This email address is already used, Please go to login to complete the subscription:<a href='https://example.de/login/'>Click Here</a>", 'leaky_paywall' ), 'register' );
}
```